# add controls to innerhtml div inside table

Tags: c#, asp.net, innerhtml

Inside a div I'm trying to add a table from codebehind.
I need to add 2 controls to this table so in order to do this I put the code in the `Page_Init()` but it won't add the controls so what should I do to resolve this or should I go a completely different way.

my code:

```
if ((List<ShoppingCart>)Session["shoppin"] != null)
        {
            string cartcontent = "";
            TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
            txtbox.TextChanged +=new EventHandler(txtbox_TextChanged);
            txtbox.CssClass = "carttextbox";
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Click +=new EventHandler(btn_Click);
            btn.Text = "Remove";
            btn.CssClass = "cartbtn";
            maincontent.Controls.Add(txtbox);
            maincontent.Controls.Add(btn);

            foreach (ShoppingCart r in (List<ShoppingCart>)Session["shoppin"])
            {
                cartcontent = cartcontent + "<tr class='row'>" +
                    "<td class='cart_prods'>" +
                    "<table>" +
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td colspan='2'><b>" + r.ProductName + "</b></td>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td align='center' style='width:100%'> <img src='" + r.ProductImage + "' alt='' style='max-height:150px' /></td>" +
                    "<td><div class='.cart_products_options'><i>" + r.ProductOptions + "</i></div></td>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                    "</table>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td class='cart_update' style='border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;'>" + txtbox + btn + "</td>" + 
                    "<td class='cart_price' style='border-width: 0px 0px 1px;'><span class='ProductSpecialPrice'> $"+ r.ProductPrice + "</span></td>"
                    +"</tr>";
                double pricetotal = 0;
                pricetotal = pricetotal + r.ProductPrice;
            }

            maincontent.InnerHtml = "<table width='90%' style='margin:0 auto; margin-top:50px;' class='cart'>" +
                "<tr align='center'>" +
                    "<th class='th1'><b>Product(s)</b></th>" +
                    "<th><b>Qty</b></th>" +
                    "<th class='th3'><b>Total</b></th>" +
                "</tr>" + cartcontent +
                "<tr class='cart_total'>" +
                    "<td></td>" +
                    "<td style='border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px; text-align:right;'>Sub-Total</td>" +
                    "<td></td>" +
                "</tr>" +
            "</table>";
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach should be simpler and also avoids adding controls dynamically:

- Create a Repeater on the page.
- Set the HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate so that it contains the opening table-tag (or closing-tag in case of the footer) and the the markup for the header and footer of your table.
- Set the ItemTemplate so that it matches the markup you build in the `cartcontent` string. Add the controls that contain the data of the shopping cart to the ItemTemplate and set the text by using data binding.
- Bind the Repeater to the `List<ShoppingCart>` if there are entries, otherwise set Visible to false.

For details on the Repeater control see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It also contains links to various tutorials.

**UPDATE:**
In order to set a value in a row dynamically without using DataBinding, e.g. for setting a total in the footer, do the following:

- Add a label to the footer, assign it an ID and set `runat="server"`.
- Add a handler to the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event of the Repeater.
- In the handler, check the type of item that is bound. If it is the footer, find the Label control and assign the value to it.

---

```
private void Rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
    {
        var lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("LabelId");
        if (lbl != null)
            lbl.Text = "123.45";
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked. Only thing no is I need to add a value from behind code to the footer and I can't get the div that I put there

Comment: @user3025852: Good to hear that it worked. I've updated my sample for the total in the footer.